# What's difference between Ionic native Firebase vs Firebase-Analytics?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-analytics

What's difference between:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/

and

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics/

I already use "firebase" for push notifications, but I need register pageviews manually, I need use these two plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ionic 'Native' Firebase** and **Ionic 'Native' Firebase Analytics** are the Ionic **wrappers** that are "providing a common interface for all plugins and ensuring that native events trigger change detection in Angular". These wrappers can't work without the plugin.

On the other side we have the Cordova Plugins as you can see in the Ionic documentation for installing a plugin.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase (1)
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase (2)
```

(1) - The Firebase Cordova Plugin that includes push notifications, event tracking, crash reporting, **analytics** and more.
(2) - The wrapper that offers you a 'gentle' interface to work with

So you can get everything you need with the Firebase plugin with OR without the Ionic Firebase wrapper.

Comment: Ok, but I can't undestand if one wrapper do anything which other don't?  Ionic Firebase (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) seems more complete...

Comment: You can definitely use the plugin without the wrapper. The wrapper is only an "interface" for the plugin that helps you to call methods easier. The specified wrapper, Ionic Firebase, only works in conjunction with cordova-plugin-firebase and Ionic Firebase Analytics works in conjunction with cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics. And yes, Firebase Plugin > Firebase Analytics (it contains Firebase Analytics).

Comment: cordova-plugin-firebase is best.