# What's the difference between the 'firebase' module, and the "Firebase" one from Ionic Native, in Ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic-native

Currently found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495251/whats-difference-between-ionic-native-firebase-vs-firebase-analytics) question (which also puzzled me), but I'm currently using "firebase" to authenticate, and "Firebase" from Ionic Native to get analytics data on the Firebase console. I think that one of these is redundant (since I have the Firebase initialization data once as an object in code, and another one in google-services.json).

So what is the difference, are these two packages substitutes for each other, or is there something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u talk about node-modules in ionic. im using if i understand to using it. and my experience tell me its not substitutes for each other. Lets talk about the modules.

First if using:

import firebase from 'firebase'
or

import * as firebase from "firebase";

1. working with dataSnapshot, snapshot, snap.
2. if i need object to array data from firebase example:

```html
import firebase from 'firebase';


this.addProduct = firebase.database().ref('/product-List'); 

this.addProduct.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.productList = [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap => {
        this.productList.push({
          category: snap.val().category,
          id: snap.key,
          in_stock: snap.val().in_stock,
          name: snap.val().name,
          downloadURL: snap.val().downloadURL,
          short_description: snap.val().short_description,
          description: snap.val().description,
          regular_price: snap.val().regular_price,
          sale_price: snap.val().sale_price,
          brand: snap.val().brand,
          vendor: snap.val().vendor
        });
      });    
     });
  }
```

another node-modules ionic-native/firebase

import {Firebase} from '@ionic-native/firebase';

1. plugin for push notifications, event tracking, crash reporting, analytics and more.
2. in my case. im using for login with phone and verifyPhoneNumber example:

```html
import {Firebase} from '@ionic-native/firebase';

 
constructor(private firebasePlugin: Firebase) {

}

Private registerPhone(): void {
    if (!this.phoneNumber.value) {
        alert('Mohon isi nomor telepon anda');
        return;
    }
      const appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
      const phoneNo = '+62' + this.phoneNumber.value;
      
     if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      try {
        this.firebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNo, 60).then (credential=> {
        //  alert("SMS Kode Verifikasi Berhasil dikirim ke Nomor Telp anda");
          console.log(credential);          
          this.showPrompt(credential.verificationId);
        }).catch (error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
        }catch(error){alert(error.message)}
      }
  }
```

Comment: So is the Ionic Native Firebase some kind of substitute for the Phonegap Push Plugin, because that is the one we use for notifications. The naming scheme though is very confusing.